# Shatnez Carpets

Tags: halacha, shaatnez

Do carpets need to be checked for Shatnez? If not, why not, especially since lets say I walk barefoot on the carpet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [R' Avrohom Miller's shatnez halacha series](http://home.comcast.net/~shatnez/halacha2.html) in which he says that according to most poskim, walking barefoot on a shatnez carpet is prohibited, or even not barefoot if the carpet is plush enough to cover part of your feet.

Comment: I wonder about that, though. The Rema (Yoreh De'ah 301:13) comments that "the skin of the [sole of the] foot is hard and doesn't benefit [from shaatnez] like other skin of the body," and therefore he (citing Tur) allows wearing a heel-less shoe made of shaatnez.

Comment: So people check their mattresses and carpets for Shatnez?

Comment: ok in the questions on the site it says

How do I get my carpet or sofa checked?
Most shatnez labs make house calls by appointment.

Comment: Does anyone know people who do this